# SSRS values separated with commas in textbox?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have a dataset (stored procedure) which returns the following data

```
Location      Type
A             None
B             None
C             Three
D             Two
E             None
F             Seventeen
G             None
```

What I need to do is display in a single textbox the following from the above data 
`C Three, D Two, F Seventeen`.

So basically I want to display all Non 'None' types.

Is it possible to do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it seems your environment is 2008R2, you can use the [LookupSet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to achieve this:

```
=Join(LookupSet(
        True
        , IIf(Fields!Type.Value <> "None", True, False)
        , Fields!Location.Value & " " & Fields!Type.Value
        , "Locations"
    ), ", ")
```

This uses `LookupSet` to get an array of the non-None rows in the Dataset (called `Locations` in my example, constructs the required `Location` + `Type` string per row, then uses `Join` to take the array and join it into a single string with the specified delimiter.